# 500 internal server error occured while calling webmethod via ajax .This is happened only in live server,its working fine in localhost

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I Tried to access availability status of a user from Database table by using ajax call in my asp.net web application.Its working perfectly in my local server,but it throw an exception when i deployed into the live server.

My ajax Code

```
<script>
    function GetUserAvailability()
    {
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "myfile.aspx/myfunction",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{'UserName':'" + document.getElementById('<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>').value + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    document.getElementById('<%=lblStatus.ClientID%>').innerHTML = response.d;
                    if (response.d == "Available") {
                        document.getElementById('<%=lblStatus.ClientID%>').style.color = "green";
                        var btn = document.getElementById("<%=btnSave.ClientID%>");
                        btn.disabled = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        var btn = document.getElementById("<%=btnSave.ClientID%>");
                        btn.disabled = true;
                        document.getElementById('<%=lblStatus.ClientID%>').style.color = "red";
                    }
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

My WebMethod

```
[WebMethod]
public static string myfunction(string UserName)
{
    Myclass db = new Myclass();
    string AvailableStatus = "Available";
    if (db.GetDetails("Tablename", "Column", "column='" + UserName.TrimEnd().TrimStart() + "'").Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        AvailableStatus = "Not Available";
    }

    return AvailableStatus;
}
```

But unfortunately,i got error code 500 internal error.Following is the error messages

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule.OnPostAcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +230


System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +138


 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +194


 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +87
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you sure `Myclass` is on the server?

Comment: yes.it is inside app_code